# PHP call callable with a variable: \App\$variable\etc

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to make the following call:

```php
$group->get('/{xxx}', \App\Actions\Test\TestMe::class);
```

However, I need to replace part of the callable with a string

```php
$foo = 'Test'
$group->get('/{xxx}', \App\Actions\$foo\TestMe::class);
```

Is there a way to do this?

The purpose is to get a different path called if the code is in a sandbox/test environment

Comment: "\\App\\Actions\\$foo\\TestMe"

Comment: What's the point of using `::class` if you already know the full class name?

Comment: @Viney - Thanks that works!

Comment: @Phil Thanks. New to this. Works without ::class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"\\App\\Actions\\$foo\\TestMe"
```

Credit to [Viney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160662/viney) who answered in comments